# How do you edit a string in C, once you've already declared it?

Tags: c

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm making a simple program in C and I've already declared two strings called: "message1" & "message2", how would I go about changing the contents of these strings? I initially fill them with "empty" for the check that happens in the segment of code shown below:

```
char message1[32] = "empty";
…
if(message1 != "empty");
{
        printf("\n[USER 1]: %s", message1);
        message1 = "empty";
}
```

After this check, if `message1` contains anything but the original value, it will then print said value and then reset `message1` to its original value of `"empty"`. However, this is obviously not the case. I've Googled for the answer and am very confused.

Comment: Please include the declaration of `message1`.  And why don't you think the code you've shown works?

Comment: what is `message1` defined as? I don't think they have a `string` type in C. Take a look at `strcmp` and `strcpy` on the google.

Comment: See [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237).  Given `char message1[32] = "empty";`, you have an array that you can modify by many possible mechanisms, including `strcpy()` and friends.  Direct assignment to individual characters also works; just ensure that the string is properly null terminated.

Comment: The comparison shown will always fail — you must use `strcmp()` or an equivalent function to compare strings in C.  The assignment shown won't compile either — you cannot assign arrays like that and need to use `strcpy()` or an equivalent function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things needs to be swapped.

#### 1.

```
if (message1 != "empty");
```

Use `strcmp()` to compare strings. The logical operators aren't used for comparison between strings in C.

```
if (strcmp(message1,"empty"))
{
    ....
}
```

#### 2.

```
message1 = "empty";
```

You can't assign arrays in C by a string. Use `strcpy` for that.

```
strcpy(message1,"empty");
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing array semantics with pointer semantics.

If your string (which is a data *format*) is stored in an array, you can change individual characters. But you cannot *assign* to an array. So this line

```
        message1 = "empty";
```

becomes a constraint violation. Instead you should use `strcpy()`, or better `snprintf()` (don't be tempted to use `strncpy()` -- it is **not** a safer `strcpy()`). Also you cannot meaningfully compare the array and a string literal. So this line

```
if(message1 != "empty");
```

also doesn't make any sense. Use the `strcmp()` function. (Also the semicolon is probably not what you want because it terminates the statement so the following compound statement is not controlled by the `if` statement.

If you don't need to modify the individual characters, then you can just use a `char *` to point to the start of a string. Then the assignment is valid, and the comparison is *probably* ok (it relies upon the compiler consolidating string literals which is not required by the standard, but all the good compilers will do this).